# taxonomy for downloading files

Tags: files, taxonomy-terms

in my e-learning website i sell my tutorials. my files are there in private folder and after paying for each set of files, users have access to download that specific set of files...
to implement that; so far i used this module: "**Private files download permission**" = Allows by-user and by-role downloads from private file system directories.
so for each set of files i have to created a separate role!
**my problem:** now i have so many roles and it is getting more difficult to organize them!

---

now i am thinking of other solutions such as using taxonomy!
i can create a form to upload a file to private folder and assign a taxonomy to it!
**1-** any user who pay for it, can get that taxonomy and can download it but i don't have a clear idea how to assign this taxonomy to a user after paying?
**2-** how can i let him download from private folder if that user has the taxonomy?
i can do it all by PHP coding and hooks but is there any module which can do half of the job at least? or if there is no module to help me...can i use Rules to check if a user has a certain taxonomy or not?

Comment: You can assign taxonomy to a node and but not a file. Are you uploading the file as a field of a node of any particular content type.

Comment: it looks a simple way but i didn't get the process clearly!
- is there a way to assign taxonomy to users?
- will the links be there inside the nodes? so can them share the links with others? i want only the user who bought that set to be able to downoad

Answer (score 1):

One easy way of doing this, is to use hook_preprocess_node(), and in that function, check for that specific term. And depending on that term, you can actually unset() that file download field in the node, and insert "Please sign up", or something, message in it's place.

Comment: i didnt find this function in drupal api

Comment: It's techically, hook_prerocess_hook(). But you use it like hook_preprocess_page(&$page), or hook_prerocess_node(&$node), etc. I mean, themename_preprocess_page, or modulename_preprocess_page, etc.

Comment: sorry to ask this question here: can i use hooks inside a node while the editor is php editor?

Comment: Some hooks. But you need to understand that this is a bad practice, having php in database.